# create permission for user to see only one view

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication, permissions

I have a db and create login and user,
this user is not able to see anything.

```
grant select on GuestView to PublicLogin
```

after this user see this view
but user can select anything

**MY QUESTION**

Why I can lock user to do any select insert / update?
I have tried this
It didn't work.

```
 SELECT 'REVOKE SELECT ON ' + quotename('dbo') + '.' + quotename('AccessCheckpoint') + ' TO PublicLogin' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

 SELECT 'REVOKE UPDATE ON ' + quotename('dbo') + '.' + quotename('AccessCheckpoint') + ' TO PublicLogin' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 

SELECT 'REVOKE INSERT ON ' + quotename('dbo') + '.' + quotename('AccessCheckpoint') + ' TO PublicLogin' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 

SELECT 'REVOKE DELETE ON ' + quotename('dbo') + '.' + quotename('AccessCheckpoint') + ' TO PublicLogin' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 

SELECT 'REVOKE EXECUTE ON ' + quotename('dbo') + '.' + quotename('AccessCheckpoint') + ' TO PublicLogin' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

but again select works normally

```
select *from AccessCheckpoint
```

Comment: In your question part it is 'Can' or 'Can't'?

Comment: I want to lock,,,
db must be closed for this user,,,,
he can only select from one view

Comment: You want PublicLogin to only have access to read from GuestView, nothing else. Right?

Comment: So; your question is 'How I can lock user to do any select insert / update?' Right?

Comment: YES   Avidan,   sv88erik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @TableUsedInView NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @TableUsedInView2 NVARCHAR(100)
SET @TableUsedInView='PulibcTable1'
SET @TableUsedInView2='PulibcTable2'

SELECT 'REVOKE SELECT ON ' + quotename(table_schema) + '.' + quotename(table_name) + ' TO PublicLogin' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_name NOT IN(@TableUsedInView,@TableUsedInView2)


SELECT 'REVOKE UPDATE ON ' + quotename(table_schema) + '.' + quotename(table_name) + ' TO PublicLogin' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES


SELECT 'REVOKE DELETE ON ' + quotename(table_schema) + '.' + quotename(table_name) + ' TO PublicLogin' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES



SELECT 'REVOKE INSERT ON ' + quotename(table_schema) + '.' + quotename(table_name) + ' TO PublicLogin' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES


SELECT 'REVOKE EXECUTE ON ' + quotename(routine_schema) + '.' + quotename(routine_name) + ' TO PublicLogin' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES

SELECT 'GRANT SELECT ON GuestView to PublicLogin'
SELECT 'GRANT SELECT ON ' + @TableUsedInView + ' TO PublicLogin'
SELECT 'GRANT SELECT ON ' + @TableUsedInView2 + ' TO PublicLogin'
```

Copy those results and paste them into a new query window and run them. You should review the output to be sure you include only the views and procedures you need.

UPDATE:

This is to make sure that the user does not have any permissions from before on the tables. If you do as I wrote above you can create the following query in the Guest View:

```
SELECT *    
    FROM PulibcTable1 AS P
    INNER JOIN PulibcTable2 AS P2 ON P.UserID=P2.UserID
```

But Public login will not be able to get rows if you have this in view:

```
SELECT *    
    FROM InternTable
```

> This is because he has access only to read from the 2 tables

Comment: I WILL DO THIS FOR ALL TABLES???
AND AFTER THIS----------

SELECT 'GRANT SELECT ON ' + TableUsedInView + ' TO PublicLogin'

SELECT 'GRANT SELECT ON ' + TableUsedInView2 + ' TO ------------
PublicLogin'
HE AGAIN CAN SELECT FROM THIS 2 TABLES?

Comment: see update :) Also be sure that not PublicLogin member of any SQL roles that gives him access. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188659.aspx